# Animation is not applied in show and hide method

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation

```
$scope.hideSampleList = function ($event) {
        $($event.currentTarget).next().hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $($event.currentTarget).next().show(300);    
    }
}
```

Animation is applied to the first four elements. After that animation is not applied. Can anyone please offer suggestions?

Comment: How? With this small piece of code we can't help. Post an example showing the issue, with all parts, html, css, js ...

Comment: your if-statement is missing, please fix the code first..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` method for animate for hide and show.

```
$($event.currentTarget).next().fadeOut(300); // hide with animation


$($event.currentTarget).next().fadeIn(300); // show with animation
```

Also have some animations like `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` or even you can use `animate()` method for custom animate.. refer [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)